# Variable time parameter in simulation for STATION block

Tags: anylogic

Welcome,

I need to set the time for the STATION block parameter in a production simulation. The idea is to make the time a variable during the simulation in ranges from, for example, 6 to 9 seconds.
In my project, the STATION block simulates one of the machines on the production line, which has variable times for processing materials.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance for a hint.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxJIf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC6m5.png)

I tried to set the times according to customDistribution(), but the time is set once for each simulation.

Comment: PS: It suffices to use the "anylogic" tag to get noticed, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If every product moving through the STATION shall get a different duration:

- Just use `uniform(6,9)` in your "Process time" field of the Station block

If all products shall use the same duration but it shall vary between model runs:

- add a parameter `p_DurationToUse` in `Main`
- use `p_DurationToUse` in your "Process time" field of the Station block
- vary the parameter as you see fit from your experiment

Comment: Does the 'uniform' change the Agent's processing time in the STATION every time, or does it randomly select a value between 6 and 9 when running the simulation? As far as I can see in the STATION parameter during simulation - the processing time does not change each time, but is constant. Once the simulation is started, the UNIFORM command randomly selects a time between 6 and 9 seconds and stays that way throughout the model. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: no. If you put `uniform(6,9)` into the "process time" property field, it is re-evaluated for each agent coming through. You can easily test that with some `traceln(time())`  commands

Comment: always open new issues for new questions and put full effort into it. This is how SOF works and how others can also benefit in the future (SOF is like a dynamic knowledge base :) ) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask