# Simulate the replacement of material components in the machine - STATION process

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a question, about the possibility of adding a command, or programming the STATION process so that after 200 agents the process stops for a period of 3 minutes (this is to simulate the replacement of material components in the machine).

I haven't tried any way because I don't know what code would work that way.

Comment: You've [already been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600003/variable-time-parameter-in-simulation-for-station-block#comment136804587_77600003) to use the `anylogic` tag when needed. Please do so in the future. You don't even mention it in your question, so to other readers your question doesn't make any sense and it will risk getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `Hold` block ahead of the `Station` logic and setup an `Event` to `hold.block()` (or `unblock()`) as needed